# What is the proper use of limit_req_zone and limit_req in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, security, rate-limiting

I have 2 website running on VPS.
Their purpose is sharing music files and publishing news. Both of them use wordpress.

What I am trying is that I want to prevent little hackers from flooding the webserver and putting stress on the server to make it crash.

The problem is that **after using** `limit_req_zone` and `limit_req` my website became very **slow**. Browsing Wordpress control panel takes a long long time. I tried changing values but it didn't improve much. I guess the problem is Wordpress because it's the only script I am using on both front and back end.

Here is the last setting which seems to be more responsive than others :

`limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=flood:5m rate=10r/m;`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
limit_req   zone=flood burst=100 nodelay;
}
```

What are the optimal values that should be used in my case (wp) ? I want the website have it's normal behavior, On the other hand stopping lifeless people from flooding.

Another question, Is it safe and enough to use `limit_req` only on php files ?

Answer (score 1):

> `rate=10r/m;`
>   You are limiting every IP to only 10 requests per minute, try to increase this!

Comment: Can you please give a hint ? I don't even know what's the normal range and what number I should hit for stopping floods. Also I have set a burst of 100. Isn't that enough ?

Comment: Typically a browser opens about 6 concurrent connections to a web site. Do some "normal" navigation on your site for a minute and look in the nginx access log how many requests came from you (your IP), add a bit of room and you can use that number of requests as a starting point.