# Best way to rate-limit all files across the entire web server in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, configuration, rate-limiting

I set up a ratelimit in my nginx config. Usually you would define a location and define the rate limit zone. I want the zone to apply on ALL **files** on the web server.

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=zone1:3m rate=5r/m;
limit_req_status 429;

server {
    listen 80 http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name SERVERNAME;

    root /var/www/cdn/public_html/;

    #SSL Config
    ssl_certificate PATH;
    ssl_certificate_key PATH;

    location / {
        limit_req zone=zone1 nodelay;
    }
}
```

I know that the location `/` does not work. That's why I am asking how to apply it to all files.

Example what i mean by a file `/files/foo.zip`

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/1091683/rate-limiting-only-the-home-page-with-nginx-limit-req-zone

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/346432/nginx-proper-use-of-limit-req-zone-and-limit-req

Answer (score 3):

The [`limit_req`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req) directive may appear in the `http`, `server` or `location` contexts.

Your `location /` block should work, if it is the **only** location in that configuration (as your example implies).

But to apply it to the entire server, the obvious placement would be the `server` block.

Comment: To apply to the entire server, just put in the `http` context instead of location blocks or server blocks, then there is no confusion.