# Rate limiting PHP requests in the absence of WordPress/WooCommerce cookies in Nginx

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

I want to rate limit PHP requests in the absence of `wp-*, wordpress-*, comment_*, woocommerce_*` cookies. I have the following configuration, which works, but it doesn't include the cookie check:

```
http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=50r/m;
}

server {
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/mysite.com$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/1091683/rate-limiting-only-the-home-page-with-nginx-limit-req-zone

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/346432/nginx-proper-use-of-limit-req-zone-and-limit-req

Answer (score 1):

you can use the map module to check for the presence or absence of cookies and then conditionally apply the rate limiting.

```
http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=50r/m;

    map $http_cookie $limit_request {
        ~wp-.* 0;
        ~wordpress-.* 0;
        ~comment_.* 0;
        ~woocommerce_.* 0;
        default 1;
    }
}
```

Modify your location block to include the rate limiting based on the absence of the specified cookies:

```
server {
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/mysite.com$fastcgi_script_name;

        # Apply rate limiting if the cookies are absent
        if ($limit_request = 1) {
            limit_req mylimit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Unfortunately, I got the `[emerg] "limit_req" directive is not allowed here` error message.